# How do I handle GPUImage image buffers so that they're usable with things like Tokbox?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, opentok, tokbox

I'm using OpenTok and replaced their Publisher with my own subclassed version which incorporates GPUImage. My goal is to add filters.

The application builds and runs, but crashes here:

```
   func willOutputSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
        videoFrame?.clearPlanes()
        for var i = 0 ; i < CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(imageBuffer!); i++ {
            print(i)
            videoFrame?.planes.addPointer(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer!, i))
        }
        videoFrame?.orientation = OTVideoOrientation.Left
        videoCaptureConsumer.consumeFrame(videoFrame) //comment this out to stop app from crashing. Otherwise, it crashes here.
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, 0)
    }
```

If I comment that line out, I'm able to run the app without crashing. In fact, I see the filter being applied correctly, but it's flickering.  Nothings get published to Opentok.

My entire codebase can be downloaded. Click here to see the specific file: [This is the specific file for the class](https://github.com/felixchan/opentok-gpuimage-filters/blob/master/HelloWorld/FilteredPublisher.swift).  It's actually pretty easy to run - just do pod install before running it.

Upon inspection, it could be that `videoCaptureConsumer` is not initialized. [Protocol reference](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTVideoCaptureConsumer.html)

I have no idea what my code means. I translated it directly from this objective C file: [Tokbox's sample project](https://github.com/JayTokBox/TokBoxGPUImage/blob/master/TokBoxGPUImage/TokBoxGPUImagePublisher.m)

Comment: please include the code where videoFrame is initialized. are you sure that videoFrame isn't nil on the crashing line?

Comment: @PatrickGoley yes, I even printed videoFrame before calling ```consumeFrame```  and it wasn't nil.  You can see the entire file here: https://github.com/felixchan/opentok-gpuimage-filters/blob/master/HelloWorld/FilteredPublisher.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I analyzed both, your `Swift`-project and the `Objective-C`-project as well. 
I figured out, that neither is working.

With this post, i want to give a first update and show a really working demo of how to use GPU image filters with OpenTok.

#### Reasons why your GPUImage filer implementation is not woring with OpenTok

#### #1 Multiple target specifications

```
let sepia = GPUImageSepiaFilter()
videoCamera?.addTarget(sepia)
sepia.addTarget(self.view)        
videoCamera?.addTarget(self.view) // <-- This is wrong and produces the flickering
videoCamera?.startCameraCapture()
```

Two sources try to render into the same view. Makes things flickering...

Part one is solved. **Next up: Why is nothing pubilshed to OpenTok?** To find the reason for this, i decided to start with the "working" `Objective-C` version.

#### #2 -The Objective-C original codebase

The orignal `Objective-C` version doesnt have the expected functionality. The publishing of the `GPUImageVideoCamera` to an `OpenTok` subscriber works but there is no filtering involved. And thats your core requirement.
The point is, that adding filters is not as trivial as someone would expect, because of differing image formats and differing mechanisms how to do asynchronous programming.

So **reason #2**, why your code isnt working as expected:
Your reference codebase for your porting work is not correct. It doesnt allow to put GPU filters in between the Publish - Subscriber pipeline.

### A working Objective-C implementation

I modified the Objective-C version. Current results are looking like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Its running smoothly.

### Final steps

This is the full code for the custom `Tok` publisher. Its basically the original code (`TokBoxGPUImagePublisher`) from [https://github.com/JayTokBox/TokBoxGPUImage/blob/master/TokBoxGPUImage/ViewController.m][2] with  following notable modifications:

#### OTVideoFrame gets instantiated with a new format

```
    ...
    format = [[OTVideoFormat alloc] init];
    format.pixelFormat = OTPixelFormatARGB;
    format.bytesPerRow = [@[@(imageWidth * 4)] mutableCopy];
    format.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    format.imageHeight = imageHeight;
    videoFrame = [[OTVideoFrame alloc] initWithFormat: format];
    ...
```

#### Replace the `WillOutputSampleBuffer` callback mechanism

This callback only triggers, when sample buffers coming directly from the `GPUImageVideoCamera` are ready and NOT from your custom filters. `GPUImageFilters` don't provide such a callback / delegate mechanism. Thats why we put an `GPUImageRawDataOutput` in between and ask it for ready images. This pipeline is implemented in the `initCapture` method and looks like this:

```
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    sepiaImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
    [videoCamera addTarget:sepiaImageFilter];
    // Create rawOut
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    rawOut = [[GPUImageRawDataOutput alloc] initWithImageSize:size resultsInBGRAFormat:YES];

    // Filter into rawOut
    [sepiaImageFilter addTarget:rawOut];
    // Handle filtered images
    // We need a weak reference here to avoid a strong reference cycle.
    __weak GPUImageRawDataOutput* weakRawOut = self->rawOut;
    __weak OTVideoFrame* weakVideoFrame = self->videoFrame;
    __weak id<OTVideoCaptureConsumer> weakVideoCaptureConsumer = self.videoCaptureConsumer;
    //
    [rawOut setNewFrameAvailableBlock:^{
        [weakRawOut lockFramebufferForReading];
        // GLubyte is an uint8_t
        GLubyte* outputBytes = [weakRawOut rawBytesForImage];


        // About the video formats used by OTVideoFrame
        // --------------------------------------------
        // Both YUV video formats (i420, NV12) have the (for us) following important properties:
        //
        //  - Two planes
        //  - 8 bit Y plane
        //  - 8 bit 2x2 subsampled U and V planes (1/4 the pixels of the Y plane)
        //      --> 12 bits per pixel
        //
        // Further reading: www.fourcc.org/yuv.php
        //
        [weakVideoFrame clearPlanes];
        [weakVideoFrame.planes addPointer: outputBytes];
        [weakVideoCaptureConsumer consumeFrame: weakVideoFrame];
        [weakRawOut unlockFramebufferAfterReading];
    }];
    [videoCamera addTarget:self.view];
    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

#### Whole code (The really important thing is initCapture)

```
//

//  TokBoxGPUImagePublisher.m

//  TokBoxGPUImage

//

//  Created by Jaideep Shah on 9/5/14.

//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jaideep Shah. All rights reserved.

//



#import "TokBoxGPUImagePublisher.h"

#import "GPUImage.h"

static size_t imageHeight = 480;

static size_t imageWidth = 640;





@interface TokBoxGPUImagePublisher() <GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate, OTVideoCapture> {

    GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;

    GPUImageSepiaFilter *sepiaImageFilter;

    OTVideoFrame* videoFrame;

    GPUImageRawDataOutput* rawOut;

    OTVideoFormat* format;

}



@end



@implementation TokBoxGPUImagePublisher



@synthesize videoCaptureConsumer ;  // In OTVideoCapture protocol



- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<OTPublisherDelegate>)delegate name:(NSString*)name

{

    self = [super initWithDelegate:delegate name:name];

    if (self)

    {

        self.view = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

        [self setVideoCapture:self];

        format = [[OTVideoFormat alloc] init];
        format.pixelFormat = OTPixelFormatARGB;
        format.bytesPerRow = [@[@(imageWidth * 4)] mutableCopy];
        format.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        format.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        videoFrame = [[OTVideoFrame alloc] initWithFormat: format];
    }

    return self;

}

#pragma mark GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate



- (void)willOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer

{

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);



    [videoFrame clearPlanes];



    for (int i = 0; i < CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(imageBuffer); i++) {

        [videoFrame.planes addPointer:CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, i)];

    }

    videoFrame.orientation = OTVideoOrientationLeft;



    [self.videoCaptureConsumer consumeFrame:videoFrame];



    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

}

#pragma mark OTVideoCapture



- (void) initCapture {
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480

                                                      cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    sepiaImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
    [videoCamera addTarget:sepiaImageFilter];
    // Create rawOut
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    rawOut = [[GPUImageRawDataOutput alloc] initWithImageSize:size resultsInBGRAFormat:YES];

    // Filter into rawOut
    [sepiaImageFilter addTarget:rawOut];
    // Handle filtered images
    // We need a weak reference here to avoid a strong reference cycle.
    __weak GPUImageRawDataOutput* weakRawOut = self->rawOut;
    __weak OTVideoFrame* weakVideoFrame = self->videoFrame;
    __weak id<OTVideoCaptureConsumer> weakVideoCaptureConsumer = self.videoCaptureConsumer;
    //
    [rawOut setNewFrameAvailableBlock:^{
        [weakRawOut lockFramebufferForReading];
        // GLubyte is an uint8_t
        GLubyte* outputBytes = [weakRawOut rawBytesForImage];


        // About the video formats used by OTVideoFrame
        // --------------------------------------------
        // Both YUV video formats (i420, NV12) have the (for us) following important properties:
        //
        //  - Two planes
        //  - 8 bit Y plane
        //  - 8 bit 2x2 subsampled U and V planes (1/4 the pixels of the Y plane)
        //      --> 12 bits per pixel
        //
        // Further reading: www.fourcc.org/yuv.php
        //
        [weakVideoFrame clearPlanes];
        [weakVideoFrame.planes addPointer: outputBytes];
        [weakVideoCaptureConsumer consumeFrame: weakVideoFrame];
        [weakRawOut unlockFramebufferAfterReading];
    }];
    [videoCamera addTarget:self.view];
    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
}



- (void)releaseCapture

{

    videoCamera.delegate = nil;

    videoCamera = nil;

}

- (int32_t) startCapture {

    return 0;

}



- (int32_t) stopCapture {

    return 0;

}



- (BOOL) isCaptureStarted {

    return YES;

}

- (int32_t)captureSettings:(OTVideoFormat*)videoFormat {

    videoFormat.pixelFormat = OTPixelFormatNV12;

    videoFormat.imageWidth = imageWidth;

    videoFormat.imageHeight = imageHeight;

    return 0;

}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you for your help.  How were you able to get the filter applied to the output buffers? Do you mind sharing your swift code?  I want to give you the bounty for this question.

Comment: Hi do you need it written in Swift? At the moment I only have the working project written in Objective-C at hand.

Comment: No, Objective-C is okay.   If you provide your objective C example it would be very helpful! Very much appreciated :) thank you

Comment: I edited my post and provided the full source code for the custom publishes class. It totally works under ObjectiveC, but i am not sure how it behaves under Swift.

Comment: Thank you @MarkusAtCvlabDotDe this is very helpful :)

Comment: I translated your code to swift and the flickering went away. However, when I subscribe to the stream, I only see black. The publisher view sees the filter applied to live video, but the subscriber view sees black. Do you have any reason why that is? This is my code: https://github.com/felixchan/opentok-gpuimage-2

Comment: weakVideoFrame is always "nil" inside the callback, do you know why?

Comment: Coming back to you soon. Wait a few days. Sry

Comment: @MarkusAtCvlabDotDe are you available for contract work?